# How to run a specific scenario from the feature file using Runner.runFeature?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where there are many scenarios in the `setup.feature` file and I only have to execute one. If I remove all scenarios and only keep one it works fine as per my requirement. But in that case I have to create a duplicate feature file for each API which doesn't seem right.

```
Map<String, Object> var = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object>testing =  Runner.runFeature("classpath:jtr/setup.feature",var,true);
```

What I tried and didn't work. Is there a way to only run a particular tag in the feature file?

```
Map<String, Object>testing =  Runner.runFeature("classpath:jtr/setup.feature",var,true).tags("@smoke");
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
Runner.runFeature("classpath:jtr/setup.feature@smoke", var, true);
```

If that doesn't work there are no plans to fix it. In my opinion `Runner.runFeature()` is a "legacy" API created in the early days only for calling a Karate feature from Java, that we plan to deprecate.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Thanks Peter.

Comment: @Maddy maybe you are on an old version of karate

Comment: I am using Karate version 1.2.0.

Comment: @Maddy maybe you are missing something